# Can't download Pytube video and get an error

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, python-3.8, pytube

I have my code here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from pytube import YouTube

root = Tk()
root.title("Youtube Downloader (highest resolution)")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.geometry("940x550+500+200")

def download():
    link = urlentry.get()
    try:
        utube_obj = YouTube(link)
        utube_obj = utube_obj.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        utube_obj.download()
        status_lbl.config(text="Download successful")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        status_lbl.config(text="Error downloading")

mainframe = Frame(root, bd=10, width=810, height=490, relief=RIDGE)
mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=40)

titleframe = Frame(mainframe)
titleframe.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=40)

widgetframe = Frame(mainframe, bd=0, width=810, height=490, relief=RIDGE)
widgetframe.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=40)

lbldownloadtitle = Label(titleframe, font="arial 30 bold", text="YouTube Video Downloader",
                         bd=7, anchor="w")
lbldownloadtitle.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

lblurl = Label(widgetframe, text="\tEnter in the entry the full URL of your video:", 
               font="arial 24", justify=CENTER, pady=24)
lblurl.grid(row=0, column=0)

urlentry = Entry(widgetframe, width=48, font="arial 22", fg="blue", justify=CENTER)
urlentry.grid(row=1, column=0)
urlentry.focus()

download_btn = Button(widgetframe, text="Download", font="arial 16", command=download)
download_btn.grid(row=1, column=1)

status_lbl = Label(root, font="arial 24", fg="blue", text="")
status_lbl.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

and it shows the error: `__init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W`
i have went to the `cipher.py` file to fix the var_regex but it doesn't work
help me about this!

Try: download video using python
Expected: video downloaded
Error: can't download

Comment: no, i download the latest version, i also changed the cipher.py file, and it still has that error

Comment: It works for me with `pytube 15.0.0` and `cipher.py` patch mentioned in the link.

Comment: i am using pytube 15.0.0, but it worked for me now, cuz i downloaded another version of python